# How does rate limiting with the Reddit and Twitch APIs work?

Tags: javascript, json, reddit, twitch

I have a question regarding rate limits with the twitch and reddit API. I am creating a simple website that requests JSON with client side JavaScript (of a particular subreddit and to test if certain streamers are online).

My question is, is the rate limit specified per user or for the total number of users using my web site? For example reddit states that there should be no more than 30 requests per 60 seconds- I'm inclined to think this is per user/bot because it says not to set your user agent to anything generic. In the case of twitch they suggest setting your client number as the httpheader to prevent rate limiting. So my two questions are if the people using my website will be making no more than 4 request a day do I  need to worry about rate limiting, regardless of how many people are using my website? Secondly do i need to set a http header or user agent if all my JavaScript is client side and I have no server side code? Sorry if the questions are blindly obvious, it's my first time working with JSON based APIs.

Twitch API details:

https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/README.md

Reddit API details:

https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After releasing my website I've discovered it's per user.

Comment: Is that for reddit, twitch, or both?

Comment: When you say "per user", is that per access token or ip?

Comment: @paranoid-android per ip.

Answer (score 0):

As of **15th of March 2024**,

- For **Reddit** is per client ID per minute.
- For **Twitch** is per client ID per user per minute.

---

## Reddit

According to the [docs](https://support.reddithelp.com/hc/en-us/articles/16160319875092-Reddit-Data-API-Wiki) under **Rate Limits**

> We enforce rate limits for those eligible for free access usage of our Data API. The limit is:
>
> - 100 queries per minute (QPM) per OAuth client id
>   QPM limits will be an average over a time window (currently 10 minutes) to support bursting requests.
>
> Traffic not using OAuth or login credentials will be blocked, and the default rate limit will not apply.
>
> **Important note**: Historically, our rate limit response headers indicated counts by client id/user id combination. These headers will update to reflect this new policy based on client id only.

---

## Twitch

According to the [docs](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/guide/#twitch-rate-limits) under **Twitch Rate Limits**

> Your app is given a bucket for app access requests and a bucket for user access requests. For requests that specify a user access token, the limits are applied per client ID per user per minute.